# What is the difference between q-value and adjusted p-value (p.adjust)?

Tags: r, p-value, false-discovery-rate

I know the p-value and I may know what FDR (false discovery rate) do and its goal. But I confuse between q-value (often known as FDR) and adjusted p-value (`p.ajust` in R). Are there any difference between "adjusted p-value" and q-value ?

I'm working in genomic data analysis and I use GSEA (gene set enrichment analysis) implemented in `clusterProfiler` (R package). I get p-value (Ok), p.adjsut and q-value. What should I consider as FDR ? 
In other hand I noticed that q-value is always less than "p-adjust".

Anyone can help me to understand the difference between "adjusted pvalue" and q-value ?

Comment: There is more than one way to adjust a p-value.

Comment: See https://support.bioconductor.org/p/49864

Comment: It is definitely not true that q-values (from the qvalue package) or always less than values from p.adjust() with method="BH".